# Fatal Crash in Marketing Cloud SDK (ANDROID) - RejectedExecutionException

Tags: mobilepush, android

We are frequently seeing a lot of this fatal crash in our production app.
It's our highest crash (thousands of users) with our latest release. 
Is there any way we can work around this issue?

Marketing Cloud SDK Version: 6.3.4

Android OS version affected: 8, 9, 10

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.salesforce.marketingcloud.a.c.c@d2a8f1 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4918cd6[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 4, completed tasks = 12]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution + 2078(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2078)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject + 843(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:843)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute + 1389(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1389)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute + 620(Executors.java:620)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.c.b.a + 16(b.java:16)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.analytics.c.b$1.a + 88(b.java:88)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.d.a.run + 17(a.java:17)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1162(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 636(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run + 784(Thread.java:784)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this issue?  Can you capture logs leading up to and including the incident?

Comment: Hi @BillMote , I was trying the whole day but I'm not able to reproduce it. 
This is all the logs I have. 
Could be something related with proguard ??

Comment: Have you edited, in any way, the stack trace provided?  It will not ReTrace as-is.  Without a "good" stacktrace I'm going to be unable to assist you.  Also, you're 100% sure this is from version 6.3.4 of the SDK?

Comment: Purely as an FYI, version 7.0.0 of the SDK was just released.  I am _not_ stating that it resolves the issue in your question as I have not been able to use the data you provided to retrace the error into unobfuscated code.